# ionic how to log http response in xcode

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova, cloudinary

I am trying to upload an image to cloudinary using ionic cordova plugin. I can successfully post my image to cloudinary, but the response i received in xcode shows [object Object]. I would like to get the details of the response.
 I tried printing the result using different ways such as iterating the keys of object, and nothing is been printed. is there a way for xcode to print out ionic console.log response?  My code is as follow:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaFileTransfer, $q, $base64, $translate) {
  //$scope.$inject = ['$cordovaCamera','$cordovaGeolocation','$cordovaFileTransfer'];
  $scope.imageURI = '';
  $scope.log=function(){
    console.log('hello~~~');
  };


  $scope.takePicture = function() {
    console.log('taking pictures ....');
       var uploadOptions = {
          params : { 'upload_preset': "MY_PRESET"}
        };

       var options = {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imageURI =  imageData;


            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            function win (){
              console.log('upload successful');
            }
            function fail(){
              console.log('upload fail');
            }

            return $cordovaFileTransfer.upload("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/MY_DOMAIN/image/upload", $scope.imageURI, uploadOptions);
        })
        .then(function(result){
          console.log('result is~~~~~~ ', result); 

          console.log('print the result object '); // this shows nothing
          var test1=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(result.response);
          var test2=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(result);
          console.log('test1 is ', test1); // didn't even print!!
          console.log('test2 is ', test2); // didn't even print!!
          for(var property in result[0]) {
              console.log(property + "=" + obj[property]); // nothing here
          }

          for(var property in result[1]) {
              console.log(property + "=" + obj[property]);// nothing here
          }

          for(var property in result) {
              console.log(property + "=" + obj[property]);// nothing here
          }
          var url = result.secure_url || '';
          var urlSmall;

          if(result && result.eager[0]) { // this is not working
            urlSmall = result.eager[0].secure_url || '';
            console.log('url ~~~~~~~~ is ', urlSmall); 
            chat.sendMessage(roomId,'', 'default', urlSmall, function(result){
              console.log('url is ', urlSmall);
              console.log('message image url successfully updated to firebase');
            })
          }

          // Do something with the results here.

          $cordovaCamera.cleanup();
        }, function(err){
          // Do something with the error here
          console.log('something is erroring')
          $cordovaCamera.cleanup();
        });

  };



})
```

Comment: @Nadav Ofir : how can i be able to display the success response from cloundinary when i successfully uploaded an image via Ionic unsigned upload? i tried to JSON.parse or decodeURIComponent the response, but still no luck. the decodeURIComponent actually doesn't print anything.

Comment: Maybe try using console.dir() instead of console.log()

Comment: @NadavOfir console.dir shows nothing.